# Entity Framework: Replacing an entire DbSet collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I have a generic class that performs add/update on entities of type T. The `AddOrUpdate()` method takes in a `DbSet` collection to act on as well as a list of items to add or update in the `DbSet`. The `ItemExists()` is used to check to see if an item already exists in the collection. If it does, we update. If not, we add. The method essentially compares the primary key of the item passed in with every single item in the table, and returns true (as well as the database object itself) if there's a match.

The code works fine for tables with small number of records. For larger tables however, the `ItemExists()` method is very inefficient. The method uses a foreach loop which itself is inside another foreach loop in the caller method, giving O(n^2).

An easier way would be to simply use `contextDataSet.Contains(item)`, but that throws an exception that says `Unable to create a constant value of type` which makes sense since EF can't translate the class into a SQL query. So that's a no go.

Now my actual question: is there a way to replace the entire `DbSet<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>` that gets passed in? The IEnumerable that gets passed in is bound to a datagrid on the view  and essentially includes all the items, so logically speaking, replacing the entire collection should be safe. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
public void AddOrUpdate<I, P>(Expression<Func<I, P>> dbSetExpression, IEnumerable<T> itemsToUpdate)
            where I : DbContext, new()
            where P : DbSet<T>
{
    DataFactory.PerformOperation<I>(c =>
    {
        if (m_primaryKey == null && !TryFindPrimaryKey(c))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Primary key cannot be null.");
        }

        // Get the table name from expression passed in.
        string dbsetName = ((MemberExpression)dbSetExpression.Body).Member.Name;

        var propertyInfo = c.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == dbsetName);

        // Get the values in the table.
        DbSet<T> contextDataSet = propertyInfo.GetValue(c) as DbSet<T>;


        foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
        {

            // If the primary key already exists, we're updating. Otherwise we're adding a new entity.
            T existingItem;

            if (ItemExists(contextDataSet, item, out existingItem) && existingItem != null)
            {
                c.Entry(existingItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
            }
            else
            {
                contextDataSet.Add(item);
            }
        }

        c.SaveChanges();
    });
}

private bool ItemExists(DbSet<T> itemInDbSet, T itemInList, out T existingItem)
{
    foreach (var dbItem in itemInDbSet)
    {
        // Get the primary key value in the database.
        var dbValue = dbItem.GetType().GetProperties().Single(
            p => p.Name == m_primaryKey).GetValue(dbItem);

        // Get the primary key value from the item passed in.
        var itemValue =
            itemInList.GetType().GetProperties().Single(
            p => p.Name == m_primaryKey).GetValue(itemInList);

        // Compare the two values.
        if (dbValue.ToString() == itemValue.ToString())
        {
            existingItem = dbItem;
            return true;
        }
    }

    existingItem = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As a side comment, you should consider renaming `ItemExists()` to the *semi-microsoft-ish* `TryGetItem()` nomenclature.

Comment: Are you using Proxy objects for your entities in Entity Framework?

Comment: No, I turned off proxy generation. Can turn it back on if necessary though.

Comment: This a windows app or web app.  Are these entities using the same context or different context?

Comment: WPF app. `PeformOperation<I>` creates a different context each time.